# Scaffolding models does not display specific column from row

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, model, razor-pages

I have the following table:

[image]

And the model for it:

```
 public class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Duration { get; set; }

    public enum Ratings
    {
        G = 1,
        PG = 2,
        PG13 = 3,
        R = 4
    }

    public virtual Ratings MaturityRating { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Screening> Screenings { get; set; }
}
```

In my Screening model I want to reference one of the movies so I can add a Screening:

```
  public class Screening
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Room { get; set; }
    public int Seats { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Movie")]
    public virtual int MovieId { get; set; }
    public virtual Movie Movie { get; set; }

}
```

**The problem is, the scaffolded form displays the movies in the drop-down with their ids, and it should be with their titles:**

[image]

How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Create a List in the controller to populate the dropdown. It the ViewBag Object name matches the Model property name it will be used for the dropdown items.

View

```
@*DropDownList*@
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Movie, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Movie, null, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Movie, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller Action, include

```
ViewBag.Movie = db.Movies.GetAll().Select(x=> new SelectListItem() { Name = x.Name, Value x.Id});
```

Comment: I believe this is for MVC, how does it work with Razor Pages?

Comment: I did not know it was razor pages, can you show your cshtml file as well?